# HowTo have multiple SPI implementations in one JAR

Tags: java

Assume I have one interface `com.example.Marker` and I do have one implementation of this, eg `com.example.MarkerImplA`. To get one of them registered, I need to place a text file in `META-INF/services/com.example.Marker` looking like this

```
com.example.MarkerImplA
```

This works like a charme. Now, I have another implementation in the same jar file, eg `com.example.MarkerImpl2`. How do I achieve the registration of the second one?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just add multiple lines with the fully-qualified provider's class name

So if your SPI is `com.example.Marker`

```
META-INF/services/com.example.Marker
```

add each implementation in a new line

```
com.example.MarkerImplA
com.example.MarkerImplB
com.example.MarkerImplC
```

For details take a look at the [JAR File Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html)

> Provider-Configuration File
>
> A service provider identifies itself by placing a provider-configuration file in the resource
>   directory META-INF/services. The file's name should consist of the fully-qualified name of the 
>   abstract service class. The file should contain a newline-separated list of unique concrete
>   provider-class names. Space and tab characters, as well as blank lines, are ignored. The comment
>   character is '#' (0x23); on each line all characters following the first comment character are
>   ignored. The file must be encoded in UTF-8.

**Provider lookup**

Use the [`ServiceLoader<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) that was introduced in Java **1.6**

```
ServiceLoader<Marker> markerLoader = ServiceLoader.load(com.example.Marker.class);
for (Marker marker : markerLoader ) {
     // select the marker you want or use all

     // only for demo
     System.out.println(marker);
}
```

**Prior to 1.6** you have to implement the service loader by yourself or use a library. E.g. the apache discovery library's [`Service`](http://commons.apache.org/dormant/commons-discovery/apidocs/org/apache/commons/discovery/tools/Service.html).

**A note about plug-ins**

It is possible to have multiple `META-INF/service` provider-configuration files in different deployment units, usually jar archives.

```
archive1.jar
 +- META-INF/services/com.example.Marker

archive2.jar
 +- META-INF/services/com.example.Marker
```

A lookup via the [`ServiceLoader<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) will pick up all implementations in all archives. This is done using [`ClassLoader.getResources()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources-java.lang.String-).

Thus you only have to add a jar to the classpath and the provided services can be picked up. That gives you the opportunity to build a plug-in architecture.

This is how spring works. You just add a jar to the classpath and spring features are available, because spring scans for it's service definitions. These definitions are named e.g. `spring.handlers`. Spring handlers are namespace handlers that extend the xml parsing to create [`BeanDefinition`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.2.x/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.java)s that a [`BeanFactory`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.2.x/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.java) uses to create spring beans for the [`ApplicationContext`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.2.x/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.java). See e.g. [spring-tx](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/5.2.x/spring-tx/src/main/resources/META-INF).

Comment: Thanks for this exhausting answer!